# Embedded player and content in image for wordpress

Tags: html, css, image, soundcloud

I'm trying to add custom borders around players (soundcloud and youtube) and content for my website. I don't have much experience coding outside of myspace and experimenting with codes on wordpress. I have found codes on here and across the web that helped me get the result that I want with online html editors.  When I add the code to my pages or post in wordpress, the result ends up being just the player... No Image. I attached images of examples and the codes that I got to work the best.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[This is how I want the border to fit around the players and content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5eXw.jpg)

I'm trying to paste the code that gave the closest result, but apparently its not pasting correctly because its not formatted properly (probably answers part of my question). I did get to paste the second closest code.  I actually got it work in Wordpress too. However, I have no idea how to position the player over the image correctly. The image and the play show, but not aligned.  Once again, any help is appreciated.

```
<div style="background: url(http://www.dontcursekids.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Border-1.png) no-repeat; padding: 18px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
 <iframe width="80%" height="154" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/280952276&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this, i had added the background image to `iframe`

```css
.frame_outer iframe{
  padding: 56px 49px;
    background: url(http://www.dontcursekids.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Border-1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame_outer" style="padding: 18px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
<iframe width="80%" height="154" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/280952276&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Wow. At first I couldn't get it to work but realized the first part was CSS. I'm still learning. Anyway thank you so much. It worked after I changed the dimensions and padding. Will this work for any type of post if I change the padding, dimensions, and links to sources?